# Was prophet Muhammed (PBUH) the only messenger to all mankind?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets, prophet-adam

Always thought that the prophet Muhammed(PBUH) was the only messenger for all mankind as that what i usually heard from Muslim apologists and as in this Hadith

> Abu Hurairah (may Allah be pleased with him) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) said, “I have been favored (by Allah) over all other Prophets with six (gifts which are): (i) I have been granted (the gift of uttering) the shortest expressions that bear the widest meanings, (ii) Allah made me victorious by means of awe, (by His frightening my enemies), (iii) the spoils of war were made lawful for me (iv) the earth was made for me (and my followers) a place for praying and a (means of) purification (i.e. one can pray in case there is no water through performing Tayammum (Dry Ablution, i.e. wiping one's hands with pure dust) (v) and I am the last of the Prophets.”[1]
> He (peace be upon him) also said, “Every Prophet was sent to his nation only but I have been sent to all mankind.”

but then I heard that Noah (PBUH) and Adam (PBUH) were sent for the entire mankind of that time too, for example Noah (PBUH) prayed that all disbelievers to be destroyed and his prayer got answered and only people of his nations left, also for Adam (PBUH) it was only his nation so he was like a prophet for all mankind, so what is the difference between Muhammed (PBUH) being sent for all mankind and Noah (PBUH) and Adam (PBUH) being sent for all mankind.

Comment: There is proof in hadith that noah was sent to entire mankind. Abraham was also sent to entire mankind

Answer (score 2):

Muhammad, peace be upon him, was the last messenger and the last prophet of God to humanity, not just the messenger of God. Over the years, prophets have been sent to guide people to the truth, and some of them had miracles, law, and special religion. Prophet Muhammad is the last messenger of God to bring Islam and the Qur'an. That is, there will be no new religion after the Prophet, and Islam is the last and most complete religion for humanity.

The prophets of Al-Azm, who are 5 people (Noah, Abraham, Moses, Jesus, Muhammad) and each of them brought religion and law to human beings, all had a universal mission. That is, every religion that came was for all the people of the world. And they were not dedicated to the people of their city and region. Muhammad Salawatullah Alayh was superior because he was the last messenger and had the most perfect religion. In Islam, the rules and jurisprudence are expressed about the smallest issues of life and attention is paid to all aspects of life.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B2%D9%85

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86

https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A1

Comment: To note that the contents of this contribution although citing Shia sources is shared in Sunni Islam (and other denominations).